# Why does the ID "home-ad" not work on firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am just doing a bit of css styling and ran into an issue. I was using the id "home-ad" and it would not display in Firefox. The box model would have the content size as 0x-40 (`40` was the padding value). Once I changed the ID name, the code worked without issue.

I tested it in chrome, and the `home-ad` ID displayed without issue.

I am obviously just going to use a different ID from now on, but I am curious as to why it won't display.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hajq9r9d/)

If you open it in both Firefox and Chrome, you'll see the different results.

HTML:

```
<div id="home-ad">
        <p class="text-center">First Div</p>
</div>
<div id="home-advert">
        <p class="text-center">Second Div</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#home-ad {
    background-color: #fff669;
}
#home-advert {
    background-color: #fff669;
 }
```

Comment: lol ad block probably

Comment: Do you have an adblocker installed in Firefox?

Comment: chances of having adblock enabled ? try disabling it.

Comment: I saw an answer saying it has to do with a plugin to blocks ads ... you have one?

Comment: It is the adblock causing that issue..I just checked it..

Comment: Someone trying to put ads on their page has an ad blocker installed...oh the irony

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm on my work computer and it was due to the ad blocker that's installed.

Crisis averted.